# How to check that method of a mockobject was not called only with a specific parameter?

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

I have a `PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject` of a `Logger`.

In a unit test, I do not want a call to the `warn` method to happen with a specific string parameter `doNotCallMeWithThisString`.

I have come this far:

```
public function testThis()
{
    ...

    $logger = $this->getMockLogger();
    $logger->expects($this->exactly(0))->method('warn')->with(
        $this->equalTo('doNotCallMeWithThisString')
    );
    ...
}
```

Yet this fails because `exactly(0)` marks any call to the `warn` method as an error even is the string parameter is `somethingEntirelyUnrelated`.

How can I tell the mock object that any call to `warn` is fine unless it is called with that specific string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `exactly()` method is for asserting how many times an mocked method will be called.  Unless you are using `$this->at()` for the mocked behavior, you don't specify the arguments for a specific call.  `exactly(0)`  says that the number of calls should be 0.

Change your mock to this:

```
 $logger->expects($this->any()) //Or however many times it should be called
        ->method('warn')
        ->with(
              $this->callback(function($argument) {
                  return $argument !== 'doNotCallMeWithThisString';
              })
         )
 );
```

This uses a callback to check the argument passed to the mocked method and validates that it isn't equal to your string.

[The PHPUnit documentation has the constraint types that you can use to verify the arguments of a mock.](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.assertions.html#appendixes.assertions.assertThat.tables.constraints)  At this time, it doesn't have a string not equals type.  But using the callback, you can make your own.  Your callback just needs to check the argument used and returns `true` if it is ok and `false` if it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `callback` assertion. With this, a callback method provided by you will be invoked for each time the parameter is called:

```
$logger
    ->expects($this->any())
    ->method('warn')
    ->with($this->callback(function($string) {
        return $string !== 'doNotCallMeWithThisString';
    }));
```

Some important points about this:

1. Since you don't actually care **how often** the method is called (or if it's called at all) as long as it's not called with the bad parameter, you need to use `$this->any()` as invocation count matcher.
2. The callback constraint will be invoked for each invocation of the mocked method. It **has to return `TRUE`** for the constraint to match.